# Need two sequences be positive for the limit comparison test to hold?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

According to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), the limit comparison test requires that $\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = c, 0<c<\infty \textrm{ where } a_n, b_n > 0 \textrm { for all n}$. My question is can we get rid of the requirement $a_n, b_n > 0$ and loosen the limit requirement to $\lim _{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{b_n}| = c$. Then we prove that $|a_n| \textrm{converges} \Rightarrow |b_n| \textrm{converges}$ and vice versa, and use absolute convergence to say $a_n$ converges.

Comment: Certainly, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_n}{b_n}|=c$ with $0<c<\infty$ implies $|a_n|$ and $|b_n$| converge or diverge together. The issue is $|a_n|$ converging doesn't say anything in general about $a_n$ converging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of convergence you can conclude. But divergence of  $\sum_{n}|a_n|$ does not imply that of $\sum_{n}a_n$. Take $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n},~b_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$, then the modulus limit is 1, although $\sum_n |a_n|,~\sum_n |b_n|$ are both divergent but $\sum_n a_n $ is convergent by Leibniz test.